# Create a managed Package in unlimited edition org

Tags: managed-package

I tried creating a managed package in my personal Org ( Developer Edition).But i want to Create a managed package for an org say XYZ Org (Unlimited Edition) with all metadata to be deployed to another Org.But when i try to to that i see an screen that i must use developer edition.

Can some let me know the work Around on how to create a managed package of this unlimited edition org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Move all your data in an Developer Account using Eclipse, unmanaged package, Ant migration or any other tool and from this org create a new managed package .

Because I don't think its possible to create packages from production.

Comment: Thanks a lot But why can't we create a managed package in unlimited edition even when we are paying them money for this? Is there some logic behind it

Comment: Logic could be they want a common platform for creating package. So if you have created package on unlimited edition there might be chances some functionality would not work in enterprise edition or lower editions. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to first understand the difference and use case of packaging code.

- Unmanaged packages

  Unmanaged packages are typically used to distribute open-source projects or application templates to provide developers with the basic building blocks for an application. **Unmanaged packages should not be used to migrate components from a sandbox to production organization. Instead, use Change Sets.**
- Managed packages

  Managed Packages are typically **used by Salesforce partners to distribute and sell applications to customers**. These packages must be created from a Developer Edition organization. Once Managed package is created it goes through Salesforce security review process and after that we can list that on App exchange.

So if you want to move code from one org to another org. You should use unmanged package or eclipse or ant migration tool and if it is Sandbox to PROD deployment you can use changeset as well.